# large update statement with case and multiple insert / updates in each case

Tags: sql-server, loops, case, procedure

I am not sure how to ask this question but here goes.  I am trying to write a procedure to run each night that checks all unpaid invoices for a business and then adds service charge if needed.  I need to query unpaid invoices, then check datediff() between creation and current date and then at certain values like 15 or 30 days I need to do several insert and updates to other tables to add the service charge and update balances.  From what I read a loop is not the way to go but I am not sure how to keep track of current invoice or how to do inserts while I am inside a large update statement.  Here is some psuedocode of what I need

```
select * from invoice where ispaid = 0

set days = currentdate - invoicecreationdate

switch (days)

case 30

insert servicecharge
update invoice
update balance

case 60

insert servicecharge
update invoice
update balance due

case 90

insert servicecharge
update invoice
update balance
```

I know this isn't much to go on but I will take any help I can get.  I am not sure how this can work without a loop because I have several statements to run within each case that need to know what invoice we are currently dealing with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop wouldn't be so bad in your case.  Each pass through the loop adds 30 days to the "past due" window and it appears that you intend to process all of the applicable rows for each window as a set. That's goodness.

Alternatively, you could use something like this to generate the appropriate date ranges:

```
declare @Today as Date = GetDate();

select DateAdd( day, -( AgingDays + 30 ), @Today ) as StartDate,
  DateAdd( day, -( AgingDays + 1 ), @Today ) as EndDate, PenaltyPercent
  from ( values ( 30, 2 ), ( 60, 5 ), ( 90, 10 ) ) as PastDueIntervals( AgingDays, PenaltyPercent )
```

It can be easily extended to carry additional data for each range.  By JOINing this with your `Invoice` table you can process all the applicable invoices at once.

Depending on the size of you tables it may make sense to generate a temporary table that contains the invoice id, past due interval and any other applicable data. That table can then be used to supply the information used to update all three tables.

A useful trick is to include a `CASE` in `UPDATE` statements, e.g.:

```
update I
  set WatchList = case when Aging >= 60 then 1 else WatchList end,
    ...
  from Invoices as I inner join
    #PastDueInvoices as PDI on PDI.InvoiceId = I.InvoiceId
```

This will set the watch list flag if the temporary table indicates that the invoice is 60 days or more past due, otherwise leave it unchanged.

Comment: thank you.  I am going to try a loop and temp table and see what I can do.  I have to update and insert several things for each invoice past due so I think that will be easier.  Never used a temp table so here goes nothing.